# Why define an object in onActivityResult dosen't make sense?

Tags: java, android, android-progressbar, onactivityresult

I have four `progress` in my fragment and i define them in `onActivityResult` like :

```
 if (requestCode == GALLERY_IMAGE1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        ProgressBar progress = view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        InputStream imageStream = null;
        try {
            imageStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        bitmap = selectedImage;
        image1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + progress.getVisibility());
        editPhoto("imageName1", progress);
    }
    if (requestCode == GALLERY_IMAGE2 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        ProgressBar progress = view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        /* bunch of code */
        editPhoto("imageName2", progress);
    }
```

in my log line : `Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + progress.getVisibility());` i got 0 value which mean `GONE`.

When i try to make it visible in my editPhoto method like :

```
private void editPhoto(final String imagePosition, final ProgressBar progress) {

        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.d(TAG, "progress: " + progress.getVisibility());

/* bunch of code */

}
```

my progress dosen't came Visible and in my log line `Log.d(TAG, "progress: " + progress.getVisibility());` i get the same value `0` as above.

what i doing wrong here ?

Comment: you have to define & declare progress within onActivityResult  i.e. local , you have to  define progress  global  at top in Fragment then you can access it globally

Comment: @YogeshMane so what's wrong with my code?

Comment: downvoter can you explain why down vote on my question ?

Comment: Declare your ProgressBar on top of your Fragment. They are out of scope.

Comment: @LazarosPapadopoulos  it should throw null pointer if the progress out of scope? or i'm wrong?

Comment: [`View.GONE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE) is `8`, not `0`. [`VISIBLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#VISIBLE) is `0`.

Comment: @MikeM. thanks, you are right, it's seems my issue with views then, i think the image cover the progress. i will check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Thanks @MikeM, my fall with view behaviors, my progress was in frameLayout like:

```
<FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left">

                <ProgressBar
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar4"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/editImage4"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_images" />

            </FrameLayout>
```

and i changed it to :

```
<FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/editImage4"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_images" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar4"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>

            </FrameLayout>
```

I didn't know that frameLayout effected from this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `android:visibility="gone"` lines from your xml and do it programatically in your java file.

Comment: well, thanks, but it's work now, check my answer below.